# How to obtain value of estimated parameters in SAS (proc phreg)?

Tags: sas

How to obtain value of estimated parameters in SAS (`proc phreg`) ? I have been searching syntax `OUTPUT` and baseline but they gives only value `XBETA` ets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not into statistics, so I'm just guessing what value you mean - here's an example I think could help you:

```
ods trace on;
ods output ParameterEstimates=work.my_estimates_dataset;
proc phreg data=sashelp.class;
model age = height;
run;

ods trace off;
```

This is using SAS Output Delivery System component of SAS/Base.
With `ods trace on;`, you'll see references to parts of procedure output in SAS log:

```
Output Added:
-------------
Name:       ParameterEstimates
Label:      Maximum Likelihood Estimates of Model Parameters
Template:   Stat.Phreg.ParameterEstimates
Path:       Phreg.ParameterEstimates
```

You can refer to those (usually by Name or Path) and store them in a table with `ODS OUTPUT...` statement.
Look for SAS ODS user guide for more.